# Get the type of any user from active directory

Tags: c#, networking, active-directory, rule

Az you know every user that is defined in active directory has Type(Rule) for example Admin or Limit user,i have FirstName+LastName of any users on my local network and i want to get Type of any users from server's active directory.(domain/user only or domain/admin a person is ).what can i do?? for WinsForm.

Comment: What are you using to get data from AD? code? sql?...

Comment: take a look a this post and let me know if it solves your problem. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/active_directory_roles.aspx   :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got code I use to get Active Directory (AD) data (good article on Code Project [>> HERE <<](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/getuserfrmactdircsharp.aspx)), but I've never come across a way to read that in.

It could be that this is a custom defined field that your Network Administrator would have to set up. That would keep all the *fly-by-night* hackers from writing updates to their accounts.

What version of AD are you running? Here's some basic DirectoryEntry information from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry_members(v=vs.71).aspx